# Nest a div into another div with append in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, find, append

I am having difficulty with this simple javascript where I want to nest a div inside another div. The div looks like this.

```
<div id="div01" class="comdiv ui-widget-content" style="position: absolute; top: 40px; left: 40px; width:350px; height:250px;">
    <p id="heading" class="comhdr editableText">Editable</p>
    <div class="toolbar">
             <a href='#' title='Options' class='icotools'></a>
             <a href='#' title='Delete' class='icodelete'></a>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="link_drop_box">

      <!-- Nest div here -->

    </div>
</div>
```

In the "link_drop_box" I want to nest this div.

```
<div id="u0014" class="comurl" onmouseOver="url_preview('show', this, 'div01');" onmouseOut="url_preview('hide', this, 'div01');"><img class="dhandle" src="http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=tf1.fr" align="middle" />&nbsp;<a href="http://tf1.fr" target="_blank">TF1.fr</a> <img class="urlbutton" title="Delete" src="/icodeact/Delete16.png" onClick="delete_url('u0014');"/> <img src="/images/spacer.png" class="spacer" /> <img class="urlbutton" title="Edit" src="/icodeact/Edit16.png" onClick=""/> 
</div>
```

I try to nest this div in the previous with this javascript.

```
$('#'+card_id).find('.link_box_drop').append('<div id="'+link_id+'" class="link" onmouseOver="link_preview(\'show\', this, \''+card_id+'\');" onmouseOut="link_preview(\'hide\', this, \''+card_id+'\');"><img class="dhandle" src="http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain='+link_ico+'" align="middle" />&nbsp;<a href="'+link_info[1]+'" target="_blank">'+link_info[0]+'</a> <img class="link_button" title="Delete" src="/icodeact/Delete16.png" onClick="delete_url(\''+link_id+'\');"/> <img src="/images/spacer.png" class="link_button_spacer" /> <img class="link_button" title="Edit" src="/icodeact/Edit16.png" onClick=""/> </div>');
```

I thought that with the `.link_drop_box` selector I could get the container div with the find function, then append.  What is the right way to append an element inside that container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML contains:

```
<div class="link_drop_box">
```

Your JQuery code:
`$('#'+card_id).find('.link_box_drop')`, which should be:
`$('#'+card_id).find('.link_drop_box')`.

Comment: Thanks.  That was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#div01 div.link_drop_box:first-child').append("<div id=\"u0014\" class=\"comurl\" onmouseOver=\"url_preview(\'show\', this, \'div01\');\" onmouseOut=\"url_preview(\'hide\', this, \'div01\');\"><img class=\"dhandle\" src=\"http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=tf1.fr\" align=\"middle\" />&nbsp;<a href=\"http://tf1.fr\" target=\"_blank\">TF1.fr</a> <img class=\"urlbutton\" title=\"Delete\" src=\"/icodeact/Delete16.png\" onClick=\"delete_url('u0014');\"/> <img src=\"/images/spacer.png\" class=\"spacer\" /> <img class=\"urlbutton\" title=\"Edit\" src=\"/icodeact/Edit16.png\" onClick=\"\"/></div>");
```

this will do the trick

Comment: whats with the escape of the double apostrophes, just use single apostrophes - or am i missing something?

Comment: when you want to write apostrophes in string like " " " then you need to escape those inside in order to save string, otherwise it will be broken and error will appear. single quotes are used in methods url_preview(\'show\', this, \'div01\') I escaped them to be sure

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div.link_box_drop', $('#'+card_id))
```

This selector will return "link_drop_box" in the context of the "card_id" div.

Comment: Thanks for this tip.  Actually, there was an error in the class name link_box_drop was not right.  I needed link_drop_box.  But it was useful to learn about specifying the context.  So your suggestion also works.

Answer (score 0):

You're using [jQuery.](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works#jQuery:_The_Basics)  Yes, jquery is just a js library, but as you're doing, you'll run into plenty of problems trying to intertwine regular js with jQuery.

With the jQuery functions .find(), .append() etc, you usually, if not always, need the tag name in there before the class or id.  Ex. .find('div.link_box_drop'), or

Look over the jQuery documentation for [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) and [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Btw, it's really hard to read that much code on one line.  :-/